# Normal Map image being used for texturing

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, uv, 3d-view

[Here's a link to my files and texture images](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByTN_g1DxQR5bFVrSDh0OTBZWlk)

For some reason certain parts of my mesh are using their normal maps for texturing/color instead of the texture images I have selected for color with their respective blender materials. The result is shown below:

[image]

You can see that the hair and fins on the arm are affected. Their colors should be closer to this:

[image]

Comment: Make sure that those parts of the mesh have the correct material assigned to them

Comment: Just double checked that and they do have the desired materials assigned to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Than multitexture setting enabled, faces displays last assigned texture in UV-image editor.

Switch to **GLSL** mode, in this mode faces tries to display close to material settings:

[image]

> However, when it is set to "solid" I still see the normal map as
>   opposed to the proper texture.

If you have textures in solid mode, uncheck **textures solid**:

[image]

Comment: That seems to work for when "viewport shading" is set to "texture." However, when it is set to "solid" I still see the normal map as opposed to the proper texture.

Comment: Hmm, seems that it must have been a weird visual glitch, because after deleting and recreating the texture image the hair now displays correctly in all shading modes for the viewport.

Comment: Uncheck also "textured solid" option